# Use of unassigned local variable 'book'

Tags: c#

Hello so I was assigned this new program that I need to try and create(a phone book), and I am encountering an issue: "Use of unassigned local variable 'book'"
if you could help me it would mean a lot to me.

Here is the code on line 32.
(and if you have any tips on making my code more clear and easier to read please tell me, so I will be able to improve.)

```
using System;

namespace Phonebook
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            phonebook();
        }
        static void phonebook()
        {
            bool running = true;
            string name, address;
            string addMore;
            string phoneNumber;

            List<string> book;
            

            Console.WriteLine("Hello, this is my brand new phone book program.");
            while (running)
            {
                Console.Write("Please input the name of the person you want to input into the program ==> ");
                name = Console.ReadLine();
                book.Add(name);
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.Write("Please input the address of the person you want to input into the program ==> ");
                address = Console.ReadLine();
                book.Add(address);
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.Write("Please input the phone number of the person you want to input into the program ==> ");
                phoneNumber = Console.ReadLine();
                book.Add(phoneNumber);
                Console.WriteLine();
                if (phoneNumber.ToString().Length != 10)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Hello there, the phone number you inputed is not valid.");
                    Console.Write("Please type it again ==>");
                    phoneNumber = Console.ReadLine();
                }
                Console.WriteLine("Name: " + name + "   Address: " + address + "    Phone Numbers: " + phoneNumber);
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.WriteLine("Would you like to add more people to your contact list?");
                Console.WriteLine("Simply type 'Yes' or 'No'.");
                Console.Write(">");
                addMore = Console.ReadLine();
                if (addMore.ToLower() == "Yes")
                    continue;
                else if (addMore.ToLower() == "No")
                    break;
                else if (addMore.ToLower() == "List")
                {
                    foreach (string i in book)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(i);
                    }
                }     
                else
                    Console.WriteLine("Your input was wrong please try again.");
                    addMore = Console.ReadLine();
                    Console.Write(">");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `List<string> book;` should be `List<string> book = new List<string>();`. You _declared_ the variable, but you did not _initialize_ it.

Comment: For refactoring help, there's https://codereview.stackexchange.com. Check their "What's on-topic" page before posting.

Comment: Next issue you will be running into: Use "{}" for _all_ if/else blocks. Your code will not behave as you expect ( look at the last "else" ).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Use of unassigned local variable 'book'" is actually pretty clear about the issue:

```
List<string> book;
```

declares a variable `book`, but does not assign it a value (i.e. a List instance).

Simply make that:

```
List<string> book = new List<string>();
```

and you'll be ready for the next issue ...

---

The next issue I saw at first glance is this:

```
else
    Console.WriteLine("Your input was wrong please try again.");
    addMore = Console.ReadLine();
    Console.Write(">");
```

This is equivalent to

```
else {
    Console.WriteLine("Your input was wrong please try again.");
}
addMore = Console.ReadLine();
Console.Write(">");
```

I tend to suggest to *always* use `{}` even for one-liners:

```
else 
{
    Console.WriteLine("Your input was wrong please try again.");
    addMore = Console.ReadLine();
    Console.Write(">");
}
```

---

One more thing:

```
addMore = Console.ReadLine();
if (addMore.ToLower() == "Yes")
    continue;
else if (addMore.ToLower() == "No")
     break;
else if (addMore.ToLower() == "List")
{
      foreach (string i in book)
      {
          Console.WriteLine(i);
      }
}     
else
      Console.WriteLine("Your input was wrong please try again.");
      addMore = Console.ReadLine();
      Console.Write(">");
```

What do you expect to happen if the control flow falls through to the last `else`? (Nevermind the incorrect {} for now) The user types in a choice once more and then? Right: Nothing. It'll just move on to the next while loop iteration. You'll need to add some kind of loop here to reconsider the new input.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a new instance of your list.

```
List<string> book = new List<string>();
```